# reactjs and masonry layout - undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masonry

I have done an npm install on masonry-layout -- but when I render this component it comes up with an element undefined error? "Cannot set property 'element' of undefined"

here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/82/

I am new to reactjs and I am trying to get the masonry layout grid to work.
https://masonry.desandro.com/#package-managers

```
import React from 'react'
// import $ from 'jquery'

import Masonry from 'masonry-layout'

class VideoGrid extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.invokeMasonry()
  }

  invokeMasonry () {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.grid')
    Masonry(elem, {
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='grid'>
        <div className='grid-sizer width2' />
        <div className='grid-item width2'>
          <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div className='grid-item width2'>
          <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg' />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default VideoGrid
```

Comment: have you tried using it as jquery plugin? .i.e: $('.grid').masonry().

Comment: I believe so - similar error -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'element' of undefined

Comment: have a look: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per documentation,

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid')
    Masonry(elem, {
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true
    })
```

Should be:

```
 var elem = document.querySelector('.grid')
var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
          percentPosition: true
});
```

Comment: no - my reactjs project declines the use of "new" tag - also it will flare up an error because msnry is not used -- this isn't the problem - its as if elem is undefined when it gets invoked

Comment: elem should not be undefined as you are invoking selector on `componentDidMount `.

Comment: If you console.log(elem), do you get the elem ?

Comment: -- yes -- but still "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'element' of undefined"

Comment: I added the new -- tag and that seems to have solved it -- but then masonry renders maybe too soon - and so the elements stack -- and only toggling the width they sort themselves out properly

Comment: It is - but the masonry kicks in and just stacks the items up -- maybe its because the blocks don't have height initially

Comment: adding height seems to fix that - but then locks it down -- mm should I reload it after render?

Comment: Can't say. need to check that. Anyway your actual issue resolved. Mark answer as selected if it helped in solving.